# Macro to Print Two Different Paper Sizes at Same Zoom

Tags: excel, printing, excel-2010, vba

I set up a macro to print a large data set. It doesn't fit all on one sheet (width-wise, it can extend height-wise as needed). It prints 2/3 of the data on an 11x17 (Macro1) and the remaining 1/3 on 8.5x11 (Macro2). To get it to fit properly, I am using the following:

```
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
```

Now, this works well enough. Unfortunately, when it scales it down, the scale is not the same for both sheets so you can't place the 8.5x11 next to the 11x17 and have the rows match up. Is there anyway to pass the zoom from one macro to the other? If you set `.FitToPagesWide`, then `.Zoom` just returns false. It should also be noted, that the data set may have an additional 2 to 4 columns added. So if I set a specific zoom for my sheets, I feel like it won't work in all cases. Ideally, I would like to just fit the 11x17 and have the 8.5x11 be at the same scale.

*EDIT* I used the accepted answer and deleted out a few unnecessary items for my macro. The final code is below:

```
    .Zoom = 60
    With ActiveSheet
        Do While .VPageBreaks.Count > 2
            .PageSetup.Zoom = .PageSetup.Zoom - 1
            ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
            ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        Loop
    End With
```

*Edit 2* Current Code iteration includes a few steps to debug.

```
    With ActiveSheet
        i = 1
        .PageSetup.Zoom = 80
        Do While .VPageBreaks.Count > 2
            .PageSetup.Zoom = .PageSetup.Zoom - 1
            ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
            ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
            Application.StatusBar = "Zooming Iteration #" & i & " :: Zoom at " & .PageSetup.Zoom
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like this for some reports. Basically I just keep setting the zoom down a notch until there are no vertical page breaks. At that point you can apply the same zoom to your 2nd worksheet. This is going to be untested, but should give you a start:

```
With wsBig
    Do While .VPageBreaks.Count > 0
        .PageSetup.Zoom = .PageSetup.Zoom - 1
        ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    Loop
    wsSmall.PageSetup.Zoom = .PageSetup.Zoom
End With
```

The switching between view types was necessary to make it work, but I forget exactly why.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to actually try it yet, but I ended up using in a different macro. I am sure it will work on the macro that my question refers to as well though! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I am having issues now. It worked fine when I was stepping through the code in the VBA window using F8. Now when I just run the macro, it seems like it loops, but does not change the `.Zoom` level. I put status bar updates in there to put the zoom level in each time.

Comment: I thought that was solved by the switching back and forth between `View` types. It's been a while though, and that's clearly a bit of a hack. You don't have `ScreenUpdating` set to `False` do you? If so, try turning taking that out. If not, try saying adding `ScreenUpdating = True` below the View statements in each loop. Also a bit of a hack, but I've had it work in other situations. The goal is to do something that forces Excel to "see" the zoom changing.

Comment: Hmm, I had it set to false for the macro, but I assumed when it didn't work the first time that it should be on. I will check tomorrow to make sure I have it on. I don't remember that solving it though.

Comment: I tried it both ways. It seems to do same thing regardless. It will go up to about 27 iterations before it crashes. Normally it would go up to 150 or 250 iterations before it crashes. The .pagesetup.zoom never seems to change though regardless.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Like I say something similar works for me, and I do it across a couple dozen sheets. But it's clearly a bit of a hack, which makes it hard to debug what's not working for you. One thing I do notice in the code you added to your answer is that the starting `.zoom = 60` is outside the `With ActiveSheet` block. I assume that's not relevant, but thought I'd mention. Finally, just to be clear, if you do a `Debug.Print .Zoom` inside the loop you just get 27 60's?

Comment: I have that snippet of code within another With `ActiveSheet.PageSetup`. I set the zoom to 60 initially because I know it won't be larger then that (maybe ~50 most of the time). It was just to cut down on iterations. I will try the `Debug.Print .Zoom`. I updated the code to show my current code snippet and you can see how I was trying to debug with the status bar updates.